# How can I order a python list by the elements?

Tags: python

I have this list called scores: `[[['test', 1]], [['t', 4]], [['egrd', 8]], [['fds', 2]], [['dfs', 23]], [['wtr', 0]], [['reer', 1]]]`

I am trying to order it by the number in each element so it becomes: `[[['dfs', 23]], [['egrd', 8]], [['t', 4]], [['fds', 2]]. [['test', 1]], [['reer', 1]], [['wtr', 0]]]`

I tried looping through the array and adding elements to a new a array based on their number element like this:

```py
for x in range(0, 4): # loop through mulitple times to make sure it is ordered

    for i in range(0, len(scores) - 1):

        try:

            if scores[i][0][1] > scores[i + 1][0][1]: # compare each element against the one in front of it
                top_scores.append(scores[i]) # append to the new array

        except IndexError:
            pass
```

It returns this list: `[[['egrd', 8]], [['dfs', 23]], [['egrd', 8]], [['dfs', 23]], [['egrd', 8]], [['dfs', 23]], [['egrd', 8]], [['dfs', 23]]]`

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a lambda function as a key in order to do this :

```
sorted(scores, key=lambda x: x[0][1], reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sorted` with a custom `key` function

```
sorted(scores, key=lambda x: x[0][1], reverse=True)
```

Comment: sorry for being dumb but where do i put this? do i put it in place of the loops? or do i put it in the loops?

Comment: Just forget about the loops `top_scores = sorted(scores, key=lambda x: x[0][1], reverse=True)` and you are done!

Comment: it works! thank you so much!

Comment: @nat no problem, feel free to accept the answer if it was useful